# Permissions won't let me delete a file on a shared school server

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, permission, hacking

I'm on OS X Mavericks. When I click on **Get Info** it doesn't even have a drop down of selections for permissions. It just says read/write but it really won't let me do anything. I can't delete nor edit and save the files. I need to allow permissions to everyone including myself to edit the files, etc.

Is there anything I can do on `terminal.app` to allow myself more permission than the one given by admin?

Comment: Can you not ask the admin to change these permissions for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not the administrator or do not have the administrator credentials, there's nothing you can do. The administrator has likely setup restrictions, and the best course of action is to work with the administrator to find a suitable solution (depending on your needs).